# spring eureka - Cannot determine local hostname

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy Spring Eureka server on my local machine. Unfortunately, the Eureka application cannot determine local hostname, through this values *registered-replicas* and *unavaiable-replicas* are empty.

How I can force spring application to choose **one** network interface?

---

*Local Eureka application*

[image]

---

*pom file*

```
...
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

---

*EurekApplication.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

*application.properties*

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils= trace
```

---

*logs from console*

```
2022-12-02 13:12:35.170  INFO 13588 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:20 PM'
2022-12-02 13:12:35.828 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Software Loopback Interface 1
2022-12-02 13:12:35.830 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:35.830 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Found non-loopback interface: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:35.836 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
2022-12-02 13:12:35.882 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:35.893 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
2022-12-02 13:12:36.913  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-12-02 13:12:37.429 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Software Loopback Interface 1
2022-12-02 13:12:37.431 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:37.431 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Found non-loopback interface: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:37.437 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
2022-12-02 13:12:37.483 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
2022-12-02 13:12:37.494 TRACE 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Testing interface: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
2022-12-02 13:12:38.509  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2022-12-02 13:12:38.751  INFO 13588 --- [           main] DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration : Eureka HTTP Client uses Jersey
2022-12-02 13:12:38.806  WARN 13588 --- [           main] iguration$LoadBalancerCaffeineWarnLogger : Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is currently working with the default cache. While this cache implementation is useful for development and tests, it's recommended to use Caffeine cache in production.You can switch to using Caffeine cache, by adding it and org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager to the classpath.
2022-12-02 13:12:38.826  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2022-12-02 13:12:38.968  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-12-02 13:12:38.995  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application UNKNOWN with eureka with status UP
2022-12-02 13:12:39.009  INFO 13588 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2022-12-02 13:12:39.011  INFO 13588 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2022-12-02 13:12:39.019  INFO 13588 --- [       Thread-9] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2022-12-02 13:12:39.023  INFO 13588 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
```

---

*My local network interfaces*

[image]

Comment: Spring Cloud efforts to set the hostname are best effort. If it can't set it, you'll need to set it in properties

Comment: I have fixed it by removing VirtualBox from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should uinstall any program virtualization por example Oracle VirtualBox, VmWare WorkStation Player

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).